# Check data attribute and change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I check if data attribute has special value and then change the class?

example:

Html

```
  <li class="country active" data-country-code="ca"><div class="flag ca"></div><span class="country-name">Canada</span></li>
  <li class="country" data-country-code="us"><div class="flag us"></div><span class="country-name">United States</span></li>
   <li .........// many countries not active ></li>
```

my jQuery:

```
  var country = 'us' ; 
  $('li.country').data('country-code', country).attr('class', 'country active') ;
```

what I want from my jQuery is to replace Canada which has country `active`  and change to to USA to be `active` because I have defined country as us, and not effect other countries.
I tried to check which `country-code` is us and make the class `country active` to it.

I want it will be like this because I have country = 'us'

```
 <li class="country" data-country-code="ca"><div class="flag ca"></div><span class="country-name">Canada</span></li>
  <li class="country active" data-country-code="us"><div class="flag us"></div><span class="country-name">United States</span></li>
   <li .........// many countries not active ></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what i want from my jquery is to replace canada wich has country
>   active and change to to usa to be active because i have defined
>   country as us . and not effect other countries.

Try

```
var country = "us";
$('li.country').removeClass( "active" ).filter( "[data-country-code='" + country + "']" ).addClass( "active" );
```

Comment: `filter` ???? from which planet comes this :) , anyway it works like what i wished in my dreams :) . thanks Guru !